# Java - handling foreign characters

Tags: java, character-encoding

So, I have some Java code that fetches the contents of a HTML page as follows:

```
BufferedReader bf;
String response = "";
HttpURLConnection connection;
try 
{
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.16 Safari/534.24");
    connection.connect();
    bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
        response += line;
    }
    connection.disconnect();
}
catch (Throwable ex)
{
    response = "";
}
```

This works perfectly fine and will return the content to me as required. I then drill down to the area of code that I want to pull, which is as follows:

```
10&euro; de réduction chez Asos be!
```

Java seems to be handling the € fine since it is a HTML entity. The word "réduction" is problematic though. It seems to render it as:

10€ de r�duction chez Asos be!

As you can see it is struggling to handle the "é" character.

How do I go about solving this? I've been searching the internet and playing around with the code for the past few hours but no luck whatsoever! I'm very new to Java so it's all very difficult to get my head around.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "It seems to render it as". To render where? Anyway, do yourself a favour and study this http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: BTW: in programming there are no "foreign characters" (foreign to whom?)  YOu probably mean non-ASCII

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that when I output the string using System.out.println(string);, the console is displaying it in that way. You're right about the foreign characters, I meant foreign to me but that is of course the incorrect term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is ok but you might need to detect the character encoding of the response (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML)) and pass it to the class that wraps the inputStream to get a Reader (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html)).

Otherwise the problem is not reading the response but in the stuff you do with that response string.

Comment: Superb, thank you very much! I was aware of the character encoding in the response but didn't realise this could be passed to the inputStream. It was solved by doing this: bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "ISO-8859-1"));